# SQL creating table with foreign key results in "key": syntax error

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, datagrip, replit

I need some help with an error I'm getting with SQL. My goal is to make a simple proof of concept music database.

Te problem is that when using foreign keys I'm getting these errors:

> Error: near line 134: near "key": syntax error

I'm not sure what I'm not seeing with this syntax problem but any help is appreciated :)

My code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [Account]
(
    [AccountId]    varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    [Name]         varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    [Membership]   varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    [ArtistId]     int NULL,
    [CreationDate] date NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY ([AccountId])
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [Favorites]
(
    [Favorites] int NOT NULL,
    [AccountId] varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    [SongId]    varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    
    PRIMARY KEY ([Favorites]),
    KEY[FK_117] ([SongId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_115] 
        FOREIGN KEY [FK_117] ([SongId]) 
            REFERENCES [Song] ([SongId]),
    KEY [FK_120] ([AccountId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_118] 
        FOREIGN KEY [FK_120] ([AccountId]) 
            REFERENCES [Account] ([AccountId])
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [History]
(
    [AccountId] varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    [SongId]    varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  
    PRIMARY KEY ([AccountId]),
  
    KEY [FK_124] ([AccountId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_122] 
        FOREIGN KEY [FK_124] ([AccountId]) 
            REFERENCES [Account] ([AccountId]),
  
    KEY [FK_127] ([SongId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_125] 
        FOREIGN KEY [FK_127] ([SongId]) 
            REFERENCES [Song] ([SongId])
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [Song]
(
    [SongId]       varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    [ArtistId]     varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    [AlbumId]      varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    [Duration]     float NOT NULL,
    [Listens]      int NULL,
    [CreationDate] date NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY ([SongId]),
  
    KEY [FK_66] ([AlbumId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_64] 
        FOREIGN KEY [FK_66] ([AlbumId]) 
            REFERENCES [Album] ([AlbumId]),
  
    KEY [FK_70] ([ArtistId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_68] 
        FOREIGN KEY [FK_70] ([ArtistId]) 
            REFERENCES [Artist] ([ArtistId])
);



create table IF NOT EXISTS [Artist]
(
 [ArtistId]  varchar(45) not null ,
 [Duration]  float not null ,
 [AccountId] varchar(45) not null ,
 [Listens]   int null ,

  primary key ([ArtistId]),
  
  key [FK_73] ([AccountId]),
  constraint [FK_71] 
  foreign key [FK_73] ([AccountId]) 
  references [Account] ([AccountId])
);



create table IF NOT EXISTS [Album]
(
 [AlbumId]      varchar(45) not null ,
 [ArtistId]     varchar(45) not null ,
 [Duration]     float not null ,
 [Listens]      int null ,
 [CreationDate] date not null ,

  primary key ([AlbumId]),
  
  key [FK_76] ([ArtistId]),
  constraint [FK_74] 
  foreign key [FK_76] ([ArtistId]) 
  references [Artist] ([ArtistId])
);



create table IF NOT EXISTS [AlbumSongs]
(
 [AlbumId] varchar(45) not null ,
 [SongId]  varchar(45) not null ,

  primary key ([AlbumId]),
  
  key [FK_131] ([AlbumId]),
  constraint [FK_129] 
  foreign key [FK_131] ([AlbumId]) 
  references [Album] ([AlbumId]),
  
  key [FK_134] ([SongId]),
  constraint [FK_132] 
  foreign key [FK_134] ([SongId]) 
  references [Song] ([SongId])
);



create table IF NOT EXISTS [Playlists]
(
 [PlaylistName] varchar(45) not null ,
 [AccountId]    varchar(45) not null ,
 [CreationDate] date not null ,

  primary key ([PlaylistName]),
  
  key [FK_88] ([AccountId]),
  constraint [FK_86] 
  foreign key [FK_88] ([AccountId]) 
  references [Account] ([AccountId])
);



create table IF NOT EXISTS [PlaylistSongs]
(
 [PlaylistId] integer not null ,
 [SongId]     varchar(45) not null ,

  primary key ([PlaylistId]),
  
  key [FK_110] ([SongId]),
  constraint [FK_108] 
  foreign key [FK_110] ([SongId]) 
  references [Song] ([SongId])
);


--Insert Info
INSERT INTO Song(SongId, ArtistId, AlbumId, Duration, Listens, CreationDate)
VALUES ('Feel it Still', 'Confetti', 'Rampage', 127, 120000, 10-20-2000),
 ('Hot', '2WEI', 'Guilty', 189, 9753, 7-9-2000),
 ('Run', 'Queen', 'The Cinema', 89, 89600, 1-20-2000);

INSERT INTO Account (AccountId, Name, Membership, ArtistId, CreationDate)
VALUES (1, 'Tom B. Erichsen', 'Premium', 'Confetti', 10-20-2000),
 (2, 'Anna L. Lander', 'Free', 'Queen', 10-20-1999),
 (3, 'Ned B. Flanders', 'Premium', null, 10-20-2010);

INSERT INTO Favorites (AccountId, SongId)
VALUES (1, 'Feel it Still'),
 (2, 'Hot'),
 (3, 'Run');

INSERT INTO History(AccountId, SongId)
VALUES (1, 'Run'),
 (3, 'Hot'),
 (2, 'Feel it Still');

INSERT INTO Artist(ArtistId, AccountId, Duration, Listens)
VALUES ('Confetti','Tom B. Erichsens', 97091, 3457678),
 ('2WEI', null, 23897, 34556),
 ('Queen','Ned B. Flanders', 490783, 89734);

INSERT INTO Album(ArtistId, AlbumId)
VALUES ('Confetti', 'Rampage'),
 ('2WEI', 'Guilty'),
 ('Queen', 'The Cinema');

INSERT INTO AlbumSongs(AlbumId, SongId)
VALUES ('Rampage', 'Feel it Still'),
 ('Guilty', 'Hot'),
 ('The Cinema', 'Run');

INSERT INTO Playlists(PlaylistName, AccountId, CreationDate)
VALUES ('Fun Car Songs', 2, 10-20-2009),
 ('Running stuff', 2, 05-21-1999),
 ('Lol',1, 07-21-1999);

INSERT INTO PlaylistSongs(PlaylistId, SongId)
VALUES ('Fun Car Songs', 'Hot'),
 ('Fun Car Songs', 'Feel it Still'),
 ('Fun Car Songs', 'Run');
```

The Error's:

```
-- Loading resources from main.sql
Error: near line 14: near "key": syntax error
Error: near line 35: near "key": syntax error
Error: near line 55: near "key": syntax error
Error: near line 79: near "key": syntax error
Error: near line 96: near "key": syntax error
Error: near line 114: near "key": syntax error
Error: near line 134: near "key": syntax error
Error: near line 150: near "key": syntax error
Error: near line 165: no such table: Song
Error: near line 175: no such table: Favorites
Error: near line 180: no such table: History
Error: near line 185: no such table: Artist
Error: near line 190: no such table: Album
Error: near line 195: no such table: AlbumSongs
Error: near line 200: no such table: Playlists
Error: near line 205: no such table: PlaylistSongs
SQLite version 3.35.5 2021-04-19 18:32:05
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
```

Comment: Everything packed in [Square brackets] looks horrible. You are trying to make `FOREIGN KEY` references to tables which are not yet `CREATE`d. And `KEY`used this way is not correct in SQLite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some lines starting with the word key, what do you expect them to do?
Like this one:

```
 key [FK_117] ([SongId]),
```

I think that these are your problem.